# Remove space when using flex-direction: column in navbar - bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using the basic navbar: (First example on their site)  I am also using flex-direction set to "column" to show image above menu items.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

I have a logo that I want to place with links right below.  However, there is an empty space in between the image and the links: (Squiggly line red section below)

[image]

My question is, how do I get rid of that space so that image and menu items have zero space in between them?  Also, what would be the correct bootstrap code to make the menu items stretch to be the same exact width as the image?  I have included an entire sample below.  To recreate the issue, "run code snippet" and select "full page". Thank You!

```css
#mynavbar{
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#mynavbarinside{
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
<body>
<nav id="mynavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div class="container-fluid" style="flex-direction: column;">
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <img src="https://shapedplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Create-a-full-width-ticker-logo-carousel.png" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div id="mynavbarinside" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul id="site_nav" class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="http://link01" target="_blank">
                                    Link<br>
                                    One
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="http://link02" target="_blank">
                                    Link<br>
                                    Two
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="http://link03" target="_blank">
                                    Link<br>
                                    Three
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="http://link04" target="_blank">
                                    Link<br>
                                    Four
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="http://link05" target="_blank">
                                    Link<br>
                                    Five
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `navbar-brand` which has a `padding-bottom` set by default. To remove it, add the Bootstrap class `pb-0` to the `navbar-brand`.

See the snippet below.

```css
#mynavbar {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#mynavbarinside {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav id="mynavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
         <div class="container-fluid" style="flex-direction: column;">
            <div class="navbar-brand pb-0">
               <img src="https://shapedplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Create-a-full-width-ticker-logo-carousel.png" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="mynavbarinside" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul id="site_nav" class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link01" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     One
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link02" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Two
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link03" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Three
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link04" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Four
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link05" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Five
                     </a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Rok that was it!  I marked your answer as the accepted answer. 
 By any chance would you know how to answer the second part of the question: what would be the correct bootstrap code to make the menu items stretch to be the same exact width as the image?

Comment: @RobertSmith It's not possible if you don't change the HTML (assuming you want the menu to stretch dynamically).

Comment: Hi Rok thank you again, you are correct.  I created a separate post for this since its a different question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76325517

Comment: @RobertSmith I answered the question. Actually, it's possible to achieve your goal without changing the HTML. My bad.