# Align navbar links with image - bootstrap 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using the basic navbar: (First example on their site) I am also using flex-direction set to "column" to show image above menu items.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

I have a logo that I want to place with links right below. However, I would like the links to align on each side with the image.

My question is, what would be the correct bootstrap code to make the menu items stretch to be the same exact width as the image? I have included an entire sample below. To recreate the issue, "run code snippet" and select "full page". Thank You!

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

This is an idea of how it should look aligned:

[image]

```css
#mynavbar {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#mynavbarinside {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav id="mynavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
         <div class="container-fluid" style="flex-direction: column;">
            <div class="navbar-brand pb-0">
               <img src="https://shapedplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Create-a-full-width-ticker-logo-carousel.png" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="mynavbarinside" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul id="site_nav" class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link01" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     One
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link02" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Two
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link03" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Three
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link04" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Four
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20%">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="http://link05" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Five
                     </a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Carol, I have updated and posted the complete code.  Please take a look at the included snippet.  To reproduce the problem, click on "run code snippet" and select "full page". Thank You!

Comment: Carol, I have added the closing tags.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following:

- Set `width: auto;` to the `.container-fluid`.
- Set `width: 100%;` to the `#mynavbarinside`.
- Set `margin-right: 0 !important;` to the `.navbar-brand`.
- Set `width: 100%;`, `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to the `#site_nav`. Also, remove `style="width: 20%"` from every `.nav-item`.

You can achieve all this by adding the following Bootstrap HTML classes:

- `w-auto` to the `.container-fluid`.
- `w-100` to the `#mynavbarinside`.
- `me-0` to the `.navbar-brand`.
- `w-100`, `d-flex` and `justify-content-between` to the `#site_nav`.

See the snippet below.

```css
#mynavbar {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#mynavbarinside {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="mynavbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid w-auto" style="flex-direction: column;">
      <div class="navbar-brand pb-0 me-0">
        <img src="https://shapedplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Create-a-full-width-ticker-logo-carousel.png" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div id="mynavbarinside" class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul id="site_nav" class="navbar-nav mx-auto w-100 d-flex justify-content-between">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://link01" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     One
                     </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://link02" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Two
                     </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://link03" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Three
                     </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://link04" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Four
                     </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="http://link05" target="_blank">
                     Link<br>
                     Five
                     </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```